# How to add a selectionHandle to a media widget?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am looking to customize the existing media widget for CK Editor5. I want to add the selection handle to the media widget to make it easier to select. With widgets, this can typically be done by passing an option of  `hasSelectionHandler: true` to the toWidget() function. When I attempt this with the media widget, the handle isn't added. On further inspection, I have found that the callback to create the UIElement in the addSelectionHandler() function is never called. Does anyone have a solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a very brief answer,  but I'm short on time and I hope this will help anyway.

Passing `hasSelectionHandler` to `toWidget()` makes it execute this function: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/blob/f68917cea2a58c5c1830788821ba8923f4c7c82d/src/utils.js#L362-L381.

The media embed feature doesn't use that option, so that's why the handle isn't addded to the widget.

You can change that in at least two ways:

- You can add a late callback (low priority one) to [`DowncastDispatcher#insert`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_downcastdispatcher-DowncastDispatcher.html#event-insert) and extend the media embed element created by the standard feature.
- Or you can just fork the media embed feature and use the `hasSelectionHandler` option :D